# Parsing words in C; Translating program

Tags: c, parsing, localization

I'm developing a program that will translate a string from the user (English) into Spanish.
For the assignment I'm given a file that contains a list of a 100 words and their spanish equivalent. I've successfully opened that file, and fed it to the string with a two dimensional array.

What I'm having difficulty with is parsing the words so it will allow me to find the equivalent version of the given words; any words that aren't given are suppose to be replaced with asterisks (*). Any ideas on how I can parse the words from the users inputted string?
Below is snippits of the source code to save some time.

--Thanks

```
char readFile[100][25];

fp = fopen("words.dat", "r");

if (fp == NULL){
   printf ("File failed to load\n");
}

//This is how I stored the file into the two dimensional string.
while (fgets(readFile, 100, fp)){
   x++;
}

printf ("User please input string\n");
gets (input);
```

That's as far as I've gotten. I commented out the for-loop that outputs the words so I can see the words (for the sake of curiousity) and it was successful. The format of the file string is
   (english word), (spanish word).

Comment: The code in your while loop is wrong, it will keep loading data into the first element of your "readFile" array. What is the format of the words.dat file?

Comment: Failfast: `if (fp == NULL){
   fprintf (stderr, "File failed to load\n"); exit(EXIST_FAILURE):
}

Comment: @wildplasser Failure exists, but the error code is `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: Sorry, but I I am *effectively* a DBA...

Answer (score 2):

First of, the array you declare is 100 arrays of 25-character arrays. If we talk about "lines" it means you have 100 lines where each line can be 24 characters (remember we need one extra for the terminating `'\0'` character). If you want 25 lines of 99 characters each, switch place of the sizes.

Secondly, you overwrite the same bytes of the array over and over again. And since each sub-array is actually only 25 characters, you can overwrite up to four of those arrays with that `fgets` call.

I suggest something like this instead:

```
size_t count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(readFile) / sizeof(readFile[0]) &&
                fgets(readFile[i], sizeof(readFile[i]), fp); i++, count++)
{
}
```

This will make sure you don't read more than you can store, and automatically reads into the correct "line" in the array. After the loop `count` will contain the number of lines you read.